# Ruby CSV gem returning Infinity instead of double

Tags: ruby, postgresql, csv, double, infinity

I have a method that is going through a CSV file and uploading to Postgres.

```
CSV.foreach(path, converters: :all)
```

When it encounters a number such as "2.02E+17" it is uploading "2.0150519e+17", but when it encounters "20150515E000590" it is uploading "Infinity".

If I set

```
CSV.foreach(path)
```

When it encounters "2.02E+17" it is uploading "20150519E000010" and "20150515E000590" as "20150515E000590".

I want to be uploading exactly what is shown in Excel. So in the case of "2.02E+17" I want to upload "2.02E+17", but in the case of "20150515E000590" I want to upload "20150515E000590" not "Infinity". I guess my question is how do I get CSV to not override "20150515E000590" with "Infinity"?

Comment: Why are you even bothering with Ruby when you could COPY the CSV directly into PostgreSQL?

Comment: I agree that using Postgres to load the CSV directly is the correct approach, but this is still an interesting question about the CSV lib.

Comment: Because it's not just one file I want to copy. I want to be able to hit one button every day and have a script run through whatever today's file is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Postgres can probably handle loading CSVs without Ruby's help. As for your question...

---

CSV does not define data types, so whenever you read CSV data into something that expects data types (like Excel or Ruby) the program has to guess.

When Excel sees `20150519E000010` it is guessing that this is the scientific notation 20150519e10 i.e. 20150519×10<sup>10</sup>. Excel makes a distinction between the underlying *data* in the spreadsheet and the way it is *displayed*, so in this case it opts for a shorter way of displaying that number: `2.02E+17`. So even though Excel is showing you `2.02E+17`, the **actual data** in the file is `20150519E000010`.

When you read the CSV in Ruby and tell it to convert to Ruby's data types, it makes the same guess (that it is scientific notation) but you get a different display: `2.0150519e+17`. That should be expected because `2.02E+17` is *Excel's way* of shortening the number for display. Ruby's data types do not conform to Excel. This also explains why `20150515E00059` becomes `Infinity`. 20150515×10<sup>59</sup> is too large for Ruby's floating point data type, so Ruby converts it to the largest possible float: Infinity.

However, **I strongly suspect that both Excel and Ruby are wrong**. When I see `20150515E000059`, that looks to me like `2015-05-15 00:00:59`. That's not a number in scientific notation, it's a timestamp! You can define a custom converter for handling the format:

```
CSV::Converters[:mytime] = lambda do |s|
  DateTime.parse(s.tr(?E, ?T)) rescue s
end

CSV.parse("20150515000019", converters: :mytime)
# [[#<DateTime: 2015-05-15T00:00:19+00:00 ((2457158j,19s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't realize Ruby's floats capped out before Excel's. The custom converters is also really helpful. Just to add to your answer I actually don't want "2.02E+17" because it loses it's precision. "201505190000000000" will round to "2.02E+17", but when typed back into Excel it will be "202000000000000000". Therefore it is better to use the full number and convert to the formatting I want.